# Operator cannot be applied

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new in programming. I get the error when writing this line of code :

```
var time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString().ToString();
var timePattern = "09:30";
            if (time.ToString() <= timePattern.ToString())
{
//disable the button
}
```

the error display: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `<=`

Comment: okay..i'll try to another option 1st..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply the less than equal (`<=`) operator to type `string`.

It looks like you're trying to check if the current time is less than 9:30. To do that, compare `DateTime` instances.

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
//Creates a DateTime instance with the current year, month, day at 9:30AM
DateTime nineThirty = 
    new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 9, 30, 0);
if(currentTime.TimeOfDay <= nineThirty.TimeOfDay)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: One more think..i tried to do timer.so by writing this,i dont need to use timer right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without specifying year/month/day...

```
        if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0))
        {
            // ... it's before 9:30 am ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The <= operator is not defined for the values of strings.
You should instead make your comparisons in terms of DateTime instances

Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do not turn DateTimes into strings to compare them, use the DateTimes directly.

To turn a string into a DateTime, use DateTime.Parse or [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx)

**Note**

To compare strings:

Use `String.Compare` to [compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx) strings like this.

`<=` hasn't been implemented for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing `DateTime`s directly, not converting them to strings. The [`<=` operator has been implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986512.aspx) for `DateTime` so it should be as easy as:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
var timePattern = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, time.Day, 9, 30, 0);
if (time <= timePattern)
{
    //disable the button
}
```

---

FYI you cannot use `<=` for strings, you will need to use [`string.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a.aspx) instead.

```
if (time.ToString().CompareTo(timeParrent.ToString()) <= 0)
```

Or the `static` method [`string.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx) for an alternative syntax.

```
if (string.Compare(time.ToString(), timeParrent.ToString()) <= 0)
```

Also `DateTime.ToShortTimeString()` won't give the format in a sortable (in all cases) format. You can use [time.ToString("u")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) to get the date as a string using the sortable date/time pattern format. An example use case where you would want to do this would be printing the date into HTML and having JavaScript sort it.